# html field alignment

Tags: html

Good afternoon,

I am new to html. I have added html form fields into my application. The textfields are not aligned and they look really untidy. This is because i have field names like 'first tag' and 'second tag' which have a text field beside it. The text field for second tag appears more towards the left compared to the first. Is there a way i can align them without using a table? if i use a table, may i know how should i do it? i am sorry i cant upload any photos since i am a new user.

below is my html code.

Thank you for any help!

Cheers,
ZhengHong

```
<div class="rightsettings">
        <form name="addsubject" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
        <br>Subject: <input type="text" name="user" /></br>
        <br>Number of tags<select name="addnoofsubject" id = "addnoofsubject" onchange="checktags()">
            <option value=1>1</option>
            <option value=2>2</option>
            <option value=3>3</option>
            <option value=4>4</option>
            <option value=5>5</option>
        </select></br>
        <div id="addfirsttag">
        <br>First Tag: <input type="text" name="tag1"/></br>
        <div id = "addsecondtag" style="visibility:hidden">
        <br>Second Tag: <input type="text" name="tag2"/></br>
        </div>
        <div id = "addthirdtag" style="visibility:hidden">
        <br>Third Tag: <input type="text" name="tag3"/></br>
        </div>
        <div id = "addfourthtag" style="visibility:hidden">
        <br>Fourth Tag: <input type="text" name="tag4"/></br>
        </div>
        <div id = "addfifthtag" style="visibility:hidden">
        <br>Fifth Tag: <input type="text" name="tag5"/></br>
        </div>
        <br><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></br>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: it needs css to proper alignment and good looking of your page..

Comment: where is your css file ??? you can use css to align all the text fields... as you are new in html so first learn it from w3school.com

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to insert your forms into tables.

```
<div class="rightsettings">
    <form name="addsubject" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
        <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="0">
            <tr><td>Subject:</td><td><input type="text" name="user" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Number of tags::</td><td><select name="addnoofsubject" id = "addnoofsubject" onchange="checktags()"> 
                <option value=1>1</option> 
                <option value=2>2</option> 
                <option value=3>3</option> 
                <option value=4>4</option> 
                <option value=5>5</option> 
            </select></td></tr>

            <tr><td>First Tag:</td><td><div id="addfirsttag"><input type="text" name="tag1"/></div></td></tr>
             <!-- all your tags like the one above -->
            <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
   <table>
    <tr style="visibility:hidden"><td>First tag :><td><input type="text" name="tag1"/></td></tr>
    <tr style="visibility:hidden"><td>Second tag :><td><input type="text" name="tag2"/></td></tr>
    <tr style="visibility:hidden"><td>Third tag :><td><input type="text" name="tag3"/> </td></tr>
   <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit"></td></tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**with a table**

```
<table>
<tr><td>First Tag</td><td><input ... /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Second Tage</td><td><input ... /></td></tr>
...
</table>
```

**with css**

css part :

```
label
{
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
}
```

html part :

```
<label for="tag1">First Tag:</label><input ... /><br />
<label for="tag2">Second Tag:</label><input ... /><br />
```

Comment: thank you for all the replies for the table. however, i am setting the fields invisible. thus, my original code has an onclick function which calls a function coded in javascript.i tried coding as below but it doesnt hide my fields anymore. <div id = "addsecondtag" style="visibility:hidden">
            <tr>
            <td>Second Tag:<td> <input type="text" name="tag2"/></td>
            </tr>
            </div>

Comment: try the property `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden`.

Inserting forms into table is not clean, prefer the css method (label)